# For an CSS animation, can I specify an already specified CSS block as a target?

Tags: css, css-animations

This sample shows an animation that transitions from a scale of 100% to a scale of 70%:

```css
.shrink {
  animation-name: title-min;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transform-origin: 0% 100% 0;
}

@keyframes title-min
{
  from { transform: scale(1); }
  to { transform: scale(.7); }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1 class="shrink">
    Hello
  </h1>
</body>
```

Now, `transform` is just a CSS property, wrapped in a block to define various targets in an animation sequence.  Is it possible to specify that block external to the `@keyframes` block as some named CSS `Ruleset` or `At-rule` and reference it in the `@keyfreames` block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, that is not possible outside of a preprocessor. In CSS, property declarations to change in an animation must appear within specific keyframe rules within the `@keyframes` at-rule.

The closest you can get is by abstracting the *values* in each keyframe to custom properties outside the `@keyframes` at-rule, then referencing them within it using `var()`, but the properties themselves (such as `transform`) still need to be specified inside the keyframe.

Comment: Hmmm. Unfortunate. :(